# https file upload using java?

Tags: java, file, file-upload, https

How can I upload a file over https(secured) using java? While I sending same as http url, it throws an exception like "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake". Can any one guide me, how to upload file in https using java? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure your testing server supports https?

Comment: are your credentials working while you login into file server normally using a browser??? also try a normal ping to server to check that its up or not.

Comment: As Sarnold says, that certainly indicates your server isn't configured for https. Ensure that it's configuration is correct and your certificate and private key are valid and ensure that there are no errors thrown by the server regarding the SSL. When you're sure the configuration is valid, verify with OpenSSL s_client.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apache [`commons-fileupload`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) , [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload) is example code

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the certificate of the ca that signed the server's certificate in a keystore, and specify the keystore path in the javax.net.ssl.trustStore system property.